# a function to read a text file

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to have a user defined function in C programming where the function would return the text from the file and filename is passed to the function via parameter to that function.
Thanks.

This is because i need to append the text to a variable. How do i modify the following code for this. This is how I tried to do this but i get lots of error now.

```
example1.c: In function ‘readfile’:
example1.c:47:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:273:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
example1.c:48:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
example1.c:48:52: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
example1.c:56:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
example1.c:56:22: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
example1.c:57:57: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
example1.c:61:59: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
example1.c:65:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
example1.c:68:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
example1.c:68:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
example1.c: At top level:
example1.c:71:30: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example1.c:71:1: error: initializer element is not constant
```

Please help.

```
char readfile (fname) {
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen ( fname , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    return buffer;
    fclose (pFile);
    free (buffer);
}
AC_ALPHABET_t * input_text = readfile("infile");
```

Comment: You'll probably need an editor to accomplish that. And two hands (or at least one hand)

Comment: You answered your question by yourself. Pass the filename as an argument and return the text. The rest is in 'your' code...

Comment: @EarlOfEgo
The return type of this function is int is it ok if i use char

Comment: There are so many mistakes. I would suggest you first learn the basics. Read some c books, or try http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Comment: *fname* has to be a `char *`, then C has to know what kind of parameters expect each of the library functions you used ; ie add a few `#include` with the right header files - for that, do, for instance `man 3 exit` in a linux terminal (or cygwin) or google "C exit manpage"

Comment: @ring0 yes i have included header files ofcourse

Answer (score 2):

This really should be easy to do with some research, but I've modified your program so that it has a function that returns a string given a filename. I imagine this isn't the easiest, best, or most correct way to do it, but you asked for a modification of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *read_from_file(const char *filename)
{
    long int size = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    if(!file) {
        fputs("File error.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    char *result = (char *) malloc(size);
    if(!result) {
        fputs("Memory error.\n", stderr);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(fread(result, 1, size, file) != size) {
        fputs("Read error.\n", stderr);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        fputs("Need an argument.\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    char *result = read_from_file(argv[1]);

    if(!result) return -1;

    fputs(result, stdout);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
[michael@michael-desktop ~]$ echo "hello world" > some_file.txt
[michael@michael-desktop ~]$ ./test some_file.txt
hello world
[michael@michael-desktop ~]$
```

I can comment the program if necessary, but looking up the function references is probably enough.

Comment: thanks after some modification to suite my code it work with few warnings like this
example1.c: In function ‘read_from_file’:
example1.c:88:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
example1.c:88:29: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]

Comment: @user1733911, did you include the <stdlib.h> header? It's defined there.